# How to set OpenGL API version in OpenTK .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, opengl, opentk

How to set OpenGl version in OpenTk 4.6.4 using .NET Core 5.0 using NativeWindowSettings class? and how to implement it correctly in this code

```
var nativeWindowSettings = new NativeWindowSettings
        {
            Size = new Vector2i(width, height),
            Title = title,
            API = ContextAPI.OpenGL,
            Profile = ContextProfile.Core,
            // APIVersion = ??
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `APIVersion` property (see also [OpenTK_hello_triangle](https://github.com/Rabbid76/c_sharp_opengl/tree/master/OpenTK_hello_triangle). e.g.:

```cs
var nativeWindowSettings = new NativeWindowSettings()
{
    // [...]

    APIVersion = new System.Version(4, 6)
};
```